# Stack pop function

Tags: java, stack

I was working on one of the algorithms problems on Leetcode, and I found out that these two different pop() functions give me different results. (of course one of them does not work)
I don't understand what the difference is.
Why does creating an int would work but the other one doesn't?

```
public void pop() {
  if ( minStack.peek() == mainStack.pop()) {
    minStack.pop();
  }
}
```

and

```
public void pop() {
  int popValue = mainStack.pop();
  if (minStack.peek() == popValue) {
    minStack.pop();
  }
}
```

Comment: Are there end values that we can see for both versions of pop()?

Comment: There is no difference. Both versions of this code work identically, unless both variables refer to the same stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in the pointer.

Once an element is popped from the stack, the pointer is moved to the next element in the stack. In this case, the first code is peeking first then popping whereas the second one is popping the element first then trying to peek.

If you look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html you'll see that when `pop()` is called (even if it's within `if` statement), it will pop that element and move the pointer to the next element.

Comment: so when I do mainStack.pop() in the if statement, I'm not evaluating the element that's been popped, instead, I'm evaluating the next element in the stack?

Answer (score 1):

If you expand out the expression into the resolution steps, this is what the first one is doing:

```
public void pop() {
  int a = minStack.peek();
  int b = mainStack.pop();
  boolean e = (a == b);
  if (e) {
    minStack.pop();
  }
}
```

And this is what the second one is doing:

```
public void pop() {
  int a = mainStack.pop();
  int b = minStack.peek();
  boolean e = (a == b);
  if (e) {
    minStack.pop();
  }
}
```

Your first code example evalutes the peek first, and compares it to the pop, so it compares the top item to itself. The second does the pop and then the peek, comparing two different items.

Try running a debugger and inspecting the list after each step

Comment: Does that mean that order matters? because I'm using peek for minStack and pop for mainStack. I don't see the difference between those two besides which one gets declared first.